# Swift: Async method into while loop

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I want to use a async function inside a while loop but the function don't get enough time to finish and the while loop starts again and never ends.
I should implement this problem with increment variable , but what is the solution? thanks a lot.
output loops between "Into repeat" - "Into function"

```
var condition = true
var userId = Int.random(1...1000)
repeat {
     print("Into repeat")
     checkId(userId, completionHandler: { (success:Bool) -> () in
     if success {
           condition = false
     } else {
           userId = Int.random(1...1000)
       }
}) } while condition


func checkId(userId:Int,completionHandler: (success:Bool) -> ()) -> () {
        print("Into function")
        let query = PFUser.query()
        query!.whereKey("userId", equalTo: userId)
        query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if object!.isEmpty {
                completionHandler(success:false)
            } else {
                completionHandler(success:true)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive function. I haven't tested this code but I think it could look a bit like this

```
func asyncRepeater(userId:Int, foundIdCompletion: (userId:Int)->()){
    checkId(userId, completionHandler: { (success:Bool) -> () in
        if success {
            foundIdCompletion(userId:userId)
        } else {
            asyncRepeater(userId:Int.random(1...1000), completionHandler:  completionHandler)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: much cleaner than the loop.  I don't think you even need the second parameter in asyncRepeater.

Comment: yes there is no need for foundidcompletion , it works very well ,thx!

Comment: I added that because I think it's better that it returns a value when it's done instead of just changing a global value.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `dispatch_group`

```
repeat {
     // define a dispatch_group
     let dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create()
     dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup) // enter group
     print("Into repeat")
     checkId(userId, completionHandler: { (success:Bool) -> () in
         if success {
           condition = false
         } else {
           userId = Int.random(1...1000)
       }
    // leave group
    dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup)
     }) 
    // this line block while loop until the async task above completed
    dispatch_group_wait(dispatchGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
} while condition
```

See more at [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25)

Comment: it seems what I need but it still does work. It only loops once but the func cant finish the query...